# How to create a nested query with 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, as shown in image.

I want a query which give me all fields from purchase_master, and package_title from package_master (purchase_master.package_id == package_master.id) + user_name from user_master (purchase_master.user_id == user_master.user_id).

[image]

I could not figure out how to join 3 tables.

Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be:

```
SELECT pum.*, pam.package_title, um.user_name
FROM purchase_master AS pum
LEFT JOIN package_master AS pam ON pam.package_id = pam.id
LEFT JOIN user_master AS um ON um.user_id = pum.user_id
WHERE //some condition?
```

Is this what you require?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.package_id,a.user_id,a.package_details,b.package_title,c.user_name from purchase_master as a join paclage_master as b join user_master as c where a.package_id=b.id and a.user_id=c.user_id
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Joining three tables is same as joining two tables.

You can use following query to achieve this.

`SELECT P.PACKAGE_ID,P.USER_ID,P.PACKAGE_DETAILS,PM.PACKAGE_TITLE
FROM PURCHASE_MASTER P
JOIN PACKAGE_MASTER PM ON P.PACKAGE_ID= PM.ID
JOIN USER_MASTER U ON P.USER_ID=U.USER_ID`